# How many academic Philosophers in Australia are still influenced by John Anderson “Andersonians”

Tags: political-philosophy, politics, freedom

John Anderson was a well known Philosopher in at Sydney University whom influenced many involved in the Sydney push and the those involved in the sexual revolution of the 1960’s. Are any of his ideas about freedom of thought still influential in current philosophical circles?

Comment: Wikipedia lists a number of [academic Andersonians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Anderson_(philosopher)#Thought_and_influence), some of them well-known.